# Duplicate order confirmation

Tags: magento2.3, email, duplicate, order-confirmation

After we upgraded from Magento 2.2.7 to 2.3 we have come across that customers get duplicate confirmation emails.

I can see there is some related issues here, but not for Magento 2.3.

Anyone that might know why this is happening?

Comment: please share the email which you received.

Comment: I do not have it here atm, but what happens is when the consumer buy something they get 2 order confirmation at the same time and since we are on BCC wealso get 2 order confirmation. Both emails are identical.

Comment: so how can I check it?

Comment: What information can that tell you? I'm just wondering, it will be in Norwegian so i don't understand what type of information you need from the email.

Comment: I need the information about your website. Without it, I can not help you. thanks